# Roman numeral sections in Latex

Tags: sectioning, roman-numerals

I am trying to add roman numerals to the sections of a paper and then letters to denote the subsections. It seems the default is arabic numbers for both.

So what I have currently is:

> 1.
>        1.1
>        1.2
>   2.   2.1

And I would like:

> I.
>       I.A
>       I.B II.
>       II.A

Currently I am just using `\section` and `\subsection`, so I guess the default is numbers, but not sure how to modify section and subsection labelling for the case of roman numeral-letters I would like.

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example showcasing your setup? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Its related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26885/124842 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48655/124842 : You can use `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}` and `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}` in your preamble.