# TOC with section* AND alpha (A, B, C, etc) subsection labels

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I have two tasks I'm trying to accomplish, both of which I found independent solutions for on other threads. However, when the solutions are used in combination they conflict so I'm looking for an approach that is compatible with both

**Task 1:** use alpha labels for subsections (i.e. A, B, C, etc). This can be accomplished with `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}` as suggested in @GonzaloMedina's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48655/163476)

**Task 2:** automatically add `\section*` entries to the TOC. This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30225/163476) by @egreg suggests sticking with plain `\section` and using `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` to remove the numbering in the TOC

If I were able to successfullly combine these two tasks (which I haven't), my desired rendering would look like the following

[image: Desired TOC]
[image: Desired chapter content]

However, using @egreg's solution for task 2 causes the A, B, C subsection labels to disappear. I tried another suggestion from the same thread by @MikeRenfro to add `\renewcommand{\thesection}{}`, but as the author mentions, it leaves unnecessary indents which are not aesthetically pleasing. On a separate [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210688/163476), @Vser suggests `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:intro}}`, but in my testing this left a line of pure `...` without auto-populating the section name. The manual work to enter each name without the help of `\nameref` would be too time-consuming and difficult to maintain.

**EDIT 7/28/20:** In my actual document, I'm using `\tcolorbox` to help visually define the section headers. For instance, the following MWE along with it's rendering

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}{\setcounter{subsection}{0}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}#1]
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}} % Accomplishes task 1

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Chapter}

    \begin{strip}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title=\section*{An unnumbered section}]
            Other content here..
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{strip}
    \subsection{First Subsection}   
    \subsection{Second Subsection}  
    
\end{document}
```

[image: tcolor box section header]

Originally, I had included `\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}` in the preamble to ensure there was no extra space above, below, or left of the section title text. However, the current solution by @Bernard adds an extra blank row above the section header as seen in the rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want with `\titleformat`, the `numberless` key and the `explicit`  option from titlesec:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec,}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}{\setcounter{subsection}{0}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}#1]
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}} % Accomplishes task 1

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{A numbered section}
        \subsection{Subsection}
    \section*{An unnumbered section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works nicely on the MWE, however in my actual document I get a bunch of `Counter too large. \subsection{The Subsection Title}` - any thoughts?

Comment: There are 26 letters in the alphabet. If you have more than 26 subsections then LaTeX runs out of counters for the subsections.

Comment: If you have more than 26 sunsections, a solution would use the `\alphalph` package and redefine `\thesubsection` as  `\AlphAlph{subsection}`. This way, subsections would be labelled as  `A, B, … , Z, AA, AB, …`

Comment: @PeterWilson @Bernard Thank you for the pointers. However, I am not exceeding 26 subsections _within_ any given section. The issue appears to be the subsection counter is not reset after each new `\section*` so section1 has A, B, C and then section2 starts D, E, F. Eventually I run out of letters because there are more than 26 subsections across _all_ sections of the book

Comment: @AddisonKlinke: I've modified  `\titleformat` for unnumbered section to reste the subsection counter. Please see if it's OK now.

Comment: @Bernard Perfect! One last thing - I edited my question to show how I'm trying to format spacing around the `\tcolorbox` section titles. When I apply your solution, I get an extra blank line above each section title. I tried adding additional `0pt` parameters into your `\titleformat` function to achieve the same formatting I had before, but didn't have any luck

Comment: @AddisonKlinke: Could you please post a small complete code that we can work with instantly?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, sorry for not including that earlier. I updated the MWE now

Comment: Thank you your addition. The problem seems to be linked with  ‘other contents’. Formatting a section is not designed to add freely text to the title itself. What kind of thing  is it supposed to be?

Comment: The section title still has a blank line even when I remove the "Other content here..." line. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, but to try finding a solution, I have to understand how it is semantically linked to the title. A normal \section has for sole argument its title.

Comment: Ah it is not meant to be an additional argument to `\section`. I'm writing a guidebook, so the section title is the name of the area, and then "other content" would be details such as trail mileage, shade conditions, foliage, etc. Does that help?

Comment: I'll try to see tomorrow if I can find a solution (it's getting late here), but as I see it,  it means, more or less, the beginning of the section body should be in the \tcolorbox.

Comment: Any luck? The section body should start after the darker-colored header of the `\tcolorbox`, inside the light-colored portion